# I'm trying to use the <button class= instead of using the whole XPATH as the id: changes on each product

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

```
        from selenium import webdriver
        import time
        from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
        from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
        from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
        from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
        from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
    
    
    
        PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get("https://accounts.ebuyer.com/customer/account/index.html?action=bG9naW4=")
    
        title = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
        title.clear()
        title.send_keys("johnsmith@gmail.com")
    
        password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
        password.send_keys("pass123")
    
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]/div[4]/input').click()
    
    
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/button[2]').click()
        #accepts cookies
        driver.get("https://www.ebuyer.com/search?q=graphics+cards")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    
    
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="grid-view"]/div[1]/div[4]/button'))
            ) #finds add to basket button
        
            element.click()
    
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div/div[3]/div/a[1]').click()
            print("IN BASKET")
            #adds to basket if found
    
        except:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="main- 
                content"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a'))
            )
            element.click()
            #moves to next page
```

this is what I'm trying to click but the id changes on each product grid.

```
<button class="button button--mini-basket button--small js-add-to-mini-basket" data-product- 
id="798879" data-ajax-basket-url="https://orders.ebuyer.com/customer/products/index.html? 
action=YWpheF9jYXJ0X2FkZF9pdGVt" data-analytics-event="click" data-event-category="Search Listings -  Grid" data-event-action="Product Click" data-event-label="Add to Basket Button">Add to 
Basket</button>
```

I want to take **<button class="button button--mini-basket button--small js-add-to-mini-basket"** and
use this instead of **By.XPATH,'//*[@id="grid-view"]/div[1]/div[4]/button'**

I'm trying to scan the full page to find the Add to Basket Button and if it can't find that then it
will move on to the next page and repeat until it is found.

I have just built my first pc and I cannot get a graphics card anywhere so I want to use this grab
one.
I've recently found a love for coding so I'm quite new to this, I hope I've explained myself properly
and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use following xpath to identify. Use `element_to_be_clickable`() instead `presence_of_element_located`()

```
 element =WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Add to Basket']"))
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense but when I try it on a product that is in stock, it doesn't add it to my basket and moves onto the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Try following xpath

```
//button[@class='button button--mini-basket button--small js-add-to-mini-basket' and contains(text(),'Add to Basket')]
```